# SELECT FROM two tables?

Tags: java, jquery, sql

Using Java database connectivity can we declare a query in which we can `SELECT FROM` two tables?

Here is my code:

```
public class Invoice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int order_codej;
    java.sql.Date date1; 
    java.sql.Date date2;
    int cust_codej;
    int quantity;
    int sum;
    double pricej;
    String appellation;
    String name;
    String sname;
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Please insert order code: ");
   order_codej = input.nextInt();
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:part3";
    Connection dbcon ;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    try {
        dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"x", "x");
        stmt = dbcon.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT order_code, sent_date, order_date, Orders.cust_code," +
                                "name, surname, price, appellation, product_sum, Consists.quantity" +
                                "FROM Orders, Customers, Products, Consists" +
                                "WHERE Orders.cust_code= Customers.cust_code AND" +
                                "Orders.order_code = Consists.order_code AND" +
                                "Consists.product_code = Products.product_code" +
                                "order_code =" + order_codej  );
        while (rs.next()) {
        order_codej = rs.getInt("order_code");
        date1 = rs.getDate("sent_date");
        date2 = rs.getDate("order_date");
        cust_codej = rs.getInt("cust_code");
        quantity = rs.getInt("quantity");
        sum = rs.getInt("product_sum");
        pricej = rs.getFloat("price");
        appellation = rs.getString("appellation");
        name = rs.getString("name");
        sname= rs.getString("surname");
        }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    dbcon.close();
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
System.out.print("SQLException: ");
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
    }
}
```

*Inncorrect syntax near ".".* That's the message after compiling but it doesn't say where exactly thats my problem.

Comment: This could also be the symptom of a poorly engineered schema. If you can't modify it (e.g. working on legacy DB), at least try to create a view.

Comment: Ever heard of joins ?

Comment: I'm new at this and I don't have entirely comprehend the idea of joins. That's the answer to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

> [**Java MySQL using jquery**](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/java-mysql-insert-record-using-jquery.html)

And

> [**Visual explanation of sql joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table t1, 
  table t2
where 
  t1.id = t2.id;
```

maybe something like above?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing spaces in your SQL query code:
Example "FROM Orders, Customers, Products, Consists" +
"FROM .."
=> "FROM Orders, Customers, Products, ConsistsFROM .." without space between Consists and FROM

Comment: SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index why thiss?